# Smooth map between Riemannian manifolds of same dimension is local isometry iff. metric is preserved

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry

I am just starting to read Lee's "Riemannian Manifolds" and one of the first exercises in the text (2.7) is the following: given a smooth map $\phi:(M,g)\to (\bar{M},\bar{g})$, prove that for $\dim M=\dim\bar{M}$ we have that $\phi$ is a local isometry iff. $\phi^*\bar{g}=g$. Right to left is obvious. The converse statement, on the other hand, I'm not sure how to solve. I think I need to show that $\phi$ is a bijection, but how would I do this, only knowing that it is a local isometry? I feel like I'm making this more difficult in my head than it needs to be, and would appreciate if someone could offer a hint, or solution.
Here, the definition given for a local isometry is: for each $p\in M$ there is a neighourhood $U$ of $p$ such that $\phi |_U$ is an isometry.
An isometry is defined to be a diffeomorphism such that $\phi^*\bar{g}=g$.

Comment: So you need only to show that $\phi|_U $ is an diffeomorphism for some $U$? Inverse function theorem would do.

Comment: If $\phi$ is a local isometry, would it not follow by definition that it is a diffeomorphism on $U$?

Comment: Oh wait. I am super confused. I thought you have problem showing the other direction. But according to your definition, local isometry $\Rightarrow \phi^* \bar g = g$ is trivial, isn't it?

Comment: According to the comment section in the answer below, yes, which goes to show that I was overcomplicating matters a lot.

Comment: The previous title, "Smooth map between Riemannian manifolds of same dimension is local isometry iff. metric is preserved", was a false statement and did not appear in the question text. I updated it to be a true statement reflecting the body of the question.

Comment: I think that was actually the source of my confusion, in the first place. I thought the notation meant that $\phi$ is a global isometry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A local isometry is not always a bijection, consider for example $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow S^1$ where $\mathbb{R}$ is endowed with the Eucledean metric and $S^1$ is the quotient of $\mathbb{R}$ by the translation $t(x)=x+1$.

Comment: That doesn't really help with what I asked about, at all. Are you saying that I should be looking to prove something other than the bijectivity of $\phi$? If so, what else would it be? This feels like more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: Yes, you have to show that if $\phi$ is a local isometry, $\phi^*\bar g=g$ using the definition of local isometry in your book.

Comment: I understand that I have to do that. I posted this question because I am not sure how to achieve that. A local isometry as defined in the book means that $\phi |_U$ is an isometry. I don't see how a global property can be derived from this. Would you mind giving a hint as to what property I can use to extend it globally, if it is not bijectivity?

Comment: The point is that an isometry is defined locally, $\phi$ is an isometry on $U$ i.e to $\phi^*_{\mid \phi(U)}=\bar g_{\mid U}$. If this is true on every $U$ it implies  it is true on $M$.

Comment: Ok, in that case the implication is completely trivial. Why do we need both manifolds to be of equal dimensions, in that case?

Comment: because at a point you can have an isometry $d\phi_x:T_xM\rightarrow T_{\phi(x)}\bar M$ unless $dim(M)=dim(\bar M)$ since if $d\phi_x(u)=0$, $\|u\|\neq \|d\phi_x(u)\|$ unlees $u=0$.

Answer (score 0):

This is the exercise 2.7 of Lee's Introduction to Riemannian Manifold (e2). I write down my solution in Word document and paste screenshots below. Note that some concepts should be first recalled, that I keep Lee's notation of $\tilde{g}$ instead of $\bar{g}$ used by OP, that the condition of equal dimension is used in the right-to-left direction, and that I use [LeeSM] to refer to Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifold (e2).

[image]
[image]
We begin our proof:
[image]
[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).